# How to end processes with VBScript if runtime error occurs?

Tags: excel, vbscript

So I made a VBScript that edits excel files. The script is supposed to edit particular files, so if an unrecognizable excel file is used as input, a runtime error occurs. The problem with this is that it leaves an excel process in the background running. How can I make it so if an error occurs the process is still ended? Here is some of the basic code

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\sequencerData.xlsx")

' Perform Editing Here. Possible runtime error over here

objWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\test.xlsx", 51

objWorkbook.Close False
objExcel.Quit
```

Comment: Is your code throwing the runtime error?  If not, what exactly is causing the error?

Comment: On Error GoTo fail, use the Err object to report the mishap.

Comment: @roryap The script may encounter a runtime error depending on the contents of the Excel file. For example, if the spreadsheet doesn't have a certain worksheet, it will have a runtime error.

Comment: So then why not check ahead of time to make sure it has all the correct elements, and if not, just do whatever you need to do upon fail.  If there are conditions you anticipate, don't let errors occur...instead, deal with them in your code appropriately.

Comment: Looks like that it the solution I will have to take. Thank you